# use Pandas HDFStore to open file in read only mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, hdf5

I needed compatibility between Pandas versions, so pickle was not enough, and I stored a bunch of dataframes like this:

```
import pandas as pd

hdf = pd.HDFStore('storage.h5')
hdf.put('mydata', df_mydata)
```

...and brought them back like this:

```
df_mydata = hdf.get('df_mydata')
```

Thing is, in [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), you can usually open a file read-only like this:

```
f = open('workfile', 'r')
```

I saved the dataframes for local use as it takes too long and stresses out a server to pull them out of SQL otherwise. How can you open these `.h5` files so as to not accidentally alter them?

Comment: this might come off as sarcastic, but I mean it with all sincerity. If you don't want to alter the file, don't write code that could. Or you can copy the file and open the copy?

Comment: Do I trust myself not to write code that would alter it?.. Linux has read-write-execute permissions, and Python has this read-only mode, but maybe they are all superfluous features, like seatbelts..

Comment: In the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_hdf.html), what is meant by **mode='r' Ignored if path_or_buf is a pd.HDFStore**? Would `read_hdf` always refer to a pd.HDFStore object?

Comment: I don't know @Evan but it certainly breaks the KISS principle, and makes you less confident trusting the argument `mode` . I find myself needing read only again a few weeks later, will just put `mode='r'` and hope it doesn't ignore it.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
hdf = pd.HDFStore('storage.h5', 'r')
```

this class comes from pytables. You can read the doc here:[pytables](https://www.pytables.org/index.html)